# Storing Pickled Data in Mysql

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to use pickle to store an object in mysql, but no matter what I do, I can't seem to unpickle the data.

My mysql database

https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9g5T.png

My mysql connect function

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect (host = "localhost", user = "user", passwd = "password", db = 'database', use_unicode=True)
```

Storing the data

```
cursor.execute('UPDATE matchmaking set `elo` = %s WHERE `token` = %s', (pickle.dumps(Rating()) , y[0] ))
```

Loading the data

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM matchmaking where `gameid` = %s LIMIT 200', (row[0]))
player1 = pickle.loads(player[x][2])
```

KeyError: '"'

```
print player[x]
```

(u'35dc00eeb1fa2a49efcae7d2a8233cef', 1L, '"ccopy_reg\n_reconstructor\np0\n(ctrueskill\nRating\np1\nc_*builtin*_\nobject\np2\nNtp3\nRp4\n(dp5\nS\'tau\'\np6\nF0.35999999999999993\nsS\'pi\'\np7\nF0.014399999999999998\nsb."', 2L)

Answer (score 0):

You have double quotes around the pickled string. Use `.strip('"')` to get rid of them before `loads`. I don't know why you get the extra quotes but I'm not really familiar with MySQL.